Как получить список аннотированных тэгов с GitPython API
Мне нужно использовать GIt Python API для получения аннотированных тегов. Если я сделаю следующее:
repo = git.Repo(repo_path)
tags = repo.tags

Я получаю список lightweight (облегченных) тегов. Как мне получить список аннотированных тегов? Спасибо за любую помощь

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно пройтись по всем легковесным тэгам, и проверить, являются ли они аннотированными. https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.refs.tag.TagReference.tag это свойство возвращает или none или объект представляющий аннотированный тэг
